Does anyone know self hosted service for accepting payments and making withdrawals to wallets like bicycle in Ton but for Solana blockchain?
Solana pay is just a protocol without good implementation. Using findReference is not a scalable solution, when a hundred users can create a transfer request and all of them need to be caught in a loop using findReference.
Or tell me please a good way to do it better with findReference
